# How to move object at a specific time/frame by using geometry node instead of keyframe?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I can move object at a distance of 4meters starting from frame 24 to frame 48 using keyframes.
How can I achieve the same output by using geometry node instead of keyframes? Thank you.[image]

Comment: Hello Kaluy.. the visual effect is perfectly possible, but you should be aware that in GN, you will be moving the mesh, (or an instance)  not the object itself. Is that acceptable given the rest of your workflow?

Comment: Hello Robin, thank you for noticing my question. Yes it is fine if it will only be as an instance, what I really want to learn is how to set-up the node for the time range, like when it will start to move from frame 24 and stop at frame 48. Please kindly show me your solution thank you Robin

Comment: Chris' answer is the same as mine would have been :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just use a map range node and connect it like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much Chris, I have been searching the internet the whole day I could not find any solution. Thank you

Comment: you are welcome